# Is $k_t(x,x)\sim(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\mathrm{e}^{-tF}$ if $R=0$? (Dirac operator, heat kernels)

Tags: mathematical-physics, gauge-theory, mathematics

Let $S\to M$ be the spinor bundle and consider a vector bundle $E\to M$ with a covariant derivative $\nabla$ and associated curvature $F=F^\nabla$.

If $R=0$, the Atiyah-Singer index theorem reduces to the following equation:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathrm{ind}(D_+)=\int_M\frac{1}{k!}\mathrm{tr}\left[\left(\frac{\mathrm{i}F}{2\pi}\right)^k\right],\mathrm{dim}\;M=n=2k
\end{equation}
Consider $\mathcal{E}=S\otimes E$ and let $k_t\in\Gamma(M\times M,\mathcal{E}\boxtimes\mathcal{E}^*)$ be the heat kernel associated to $K_t:=\exp(-tDD)$. The heat equation proof of $(1)$ is based on the realisation that
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{ind}(D_+)=\mathrm{Str}(K_t)=\int_M k_t(x,x)\,\mathrm{d}x\quad\text{for all }t>0.
\end{equation}
I obtain the correct result by assuming that
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
k_t(x,x)\sim(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\exp(-t\mathcal{F})\quad\text{if }R=0,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}=\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu F_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
is the clifford curvature.

**Q:** Is $(2)$ correct? Is it a special case of a more general formula? Where can I find a proof?

Answer (score 0):

No. There are other terms. The $F$ ones are the only ones that survive the trace with the generalization of $\gamma^5$ to higher dimensions.  As to the proof, have you not yet read the Getzler paper I recommended?

Comment: Thank you! I found it difficult to understand Getzler's paper. However, I think the main result is the equation just above the Appendix: $\lim_{t\to 0}\mathrm{Str}\;k_t(0,0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\mathrm{Str}\;k^0_t(0)=(2\pi i)^{n/2}(\hat{A}(\Omega)\mathrm{ch}(F))_n$. The RHS is defined on page 3: $k_t^0(x):=(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\hat{A}(t\Omega)\exp\left[tF-\frac{1}{4t}\left(\frac{t\Omega/2}{\mathrm{tanh}\;t\Omega/2}\right)_{ij}x^ix^j\right]$. Thus, $k_t^0(0)=(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\hat{A}(t\Omega)\exp(tF)$ and if $\Omega=0$, $\hat{A}(M)=1$ and therefore $k_t^0(0)=(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\exp(tF)$.

Comment: But I wouldn't be surprised if I have misunderstood something.

Comment: Ah! I see that your $k$ is after you took the supertrace. So the answer to your original question is "yes"

Comment: I think that one of Getler's scaling equations has a typo: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317426/typos-in-getzlers-short-proof-of-local-atiyah-singer-index-theorem

Comment: I think there's a problem: Either Getzler denotes two different curvatures by $F$ (my $F$ as well as my $\mathcal{F}$) or the equation $k_t^0(0)=(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\exp(tF)$ is not what I thought it is. However, I get the right result by assuming $\lim_{t\to 0}\mathrm{str}\;k_t=\lim_{t\to 0}(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\mathrm{str}\;\exp(t\mathcal{F})$...